# What is the influence of an unused ops in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I build a graph in tensorflow like this:

```
  with tf.variable_scope('embedding'):
        self.embedding = tf.Variable(self.data.embedding, trainable=True, name="emb",dtype=self.float_type)  #
```

Then send this word embedding to the neural network model. The result seems OK.
But I want to add another embedding, for example, pos-tags, I add it like this:

```
  with tf.variable_scope('pos_embedding'):
    self.pos_embedding =  tf.Variable("emb", [self.data.pnum, self.option.pos_size])
```

The two embeddings were connected to a new embedding. But It is strange to me that alougth I only set a pos ebedding like this and do not use it the model, in other words, the embedding is only word embedding, add the above codes then result changed a lot. In my understanding, if i don't send  self.pos_embedding to any actual variables, the ops of self.pos_embedding will not excute. But the results changed a lot.

The below is my model build function. The loss function value will be changed even I only add this line: self.test_variable=tf.constant(0). Why this line of code changed the loss function value?

```
def __build_model(self):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(123)
    self.encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, self.data.max_x], dtype=self.int_type)
    self.encoder_length = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, ], dtype=self.int_type)
    self.decoder_inputs = []
    self.decoder_targets=[]
    self.target_weights=[]
    self.keep_prob = tf.placeholder(self.float_type)
    for i in range(self.data.max_y):
        self.decoder_targets.append(tf.placeholder(self.int_type,[None],name='decoder_target%d' %i))
        self.target_weights.append(tf.placeholder(self.float_type,[None,],name='target_weight%d' %i))
    with tf.variable_scope('embedding'):
        self.embedding = tf.Variable(self.data.embedding, trainable=True, name="emb",dtype=self.float_type)  
        self.test_variable=tf.constant(0) #
    self.x_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embedding, self.encoder_inputs)
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(self.option.rnn_size, initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.08, 0.08),state_is_tuple=True)
    dropout_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=self.keep_prob)
    stacked_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([dropout_cell] * self.option.num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=stacked_cell, cell_bw=stacked_cell, dtype=self.float_type,sequence_length=self.encoder_length, inputs=self.x_emb)
    output_fw, output_bw = outputs
    output = tf.concat(2, [output_fw, output_bw])
    soft_dim = self.option.rnn_size * 2
    self.softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [soft_dim, self.num_classes])
    self.softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [self.num_classes])
    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, soft_dim])
    self.logits = tf.matmul(output, self.softmax_w) + self.softmax_b

    #for predict
    self.decode_outputs_test = tf.nn.softmax(self.logits)
    self.decode_outputs_test = tf.reshape(self.decode_outputs_test, [-1, self.data.max_x, self.num_classes])

    #for training
    self.classify_out = tf.reshape(self.logits, [-1, self.data.max_x, self.num_classes])
    self.logits2 = tf.transpose(self.classify_out, [1, 0, 2])
    self.logits3 = tf.unpack(self.logits2, axis=0)
    self.loss = tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss(self.logits3, self.decoder_targets, self.target_weights, self.num_classes)
    self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.option.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
    print('model built')
```

Comment: Hey Hunter, Could you tell me how the results changed? What results changed??

Comment: @rmeertens the loss function value